# How to return selected file to android file picker from my app?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

My app appears in the file picker with the intent filter declared in my manifest for a given activity:

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            </intent-filter>
```

For example if a user wants to attach a file to an email with the gmail app, gmail opens the file picker. In this file picker is my app. The user selects my app and my app opens.
The user selects a file, which my code translates to uri.

My question is how to return this uri to the file picker?

EDIT:
As suggested by @CommonsWare follow the documentation https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters#ReturnResult. I guess "com.example.RESULT_ACTION" needs to be added to the activity's intent filter like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.mypackage.myapp.RESULT_ACTION" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

But this code doesn't work to return the uri of the selected file to the file picker for me:

```
// Create intent to deliver some kind of result data
Intent result = new Intent("com.example.RESULT_ACTION", Uri.parse("content://result_uri"));
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
finish();
```

Comment: Just the usual way. The same as if you started an activity with startActivityForResult().

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters#ReturnResult

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the answer, but the doc doesn't specify what "com.example.RESULT_ACTION" is. I guess one has to add it to the intent filter declaration of the receiving activity for example like this: "<action android:name="com.package.myapp.FILE_PICKER_RESULT"/>"? But it doesn't work with android's file picker anyway!

Comment: The action is `android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT`. That is the `Intent` action that you are attempting to respond to.

Comment: @CommonsWare No I have already tried and this is not what the documentation you link offers. This is a unique identifier including the app package that returns the uri "Intent result = new Intent("com.example.RESULT_ACTION", Uri.parse("content://result_uri")); ". That's how I understand it and you? I also don't think the uri I return is invalid since it works when I share a file directly from my app to Gmail!

Comment: "this is not what the documentation you link offers" -- overall, the documentation is for cases where *you* are both the caller (`startActivityForResult()`) and the recipient (`onActivityResult()` / `setResult()`). In your case, you are just the recipient. All you need to do is call `setResult()` at the point when you have the result that you want to send back. That is why I linked to [the specific section with the specific `setResult()` call that you need to add](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters#ReturnResult).

Comment: You could also look at [many sample implementations of `GET_CONTENT` handlers](https://github.com/search?q=%22%3Caction+android%3Aname%3D%5C%22android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT%5C%22+%2F%3E%22+language%3AXML&type=code) and see how they handle it. Only a subset of those are activities for handling `GET_CONTENT`, but that's as close as I can get with my knowledge of GitHub search syntax.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks I searched the codes on github and found the solution (see answer)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the return code that works for me.
Attention, the activity that is declared the intent filter must be the one that sends the result.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri,mime);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
```